# How to refresh data retrieved from SQLite when table is updated in React Native?

Tags: sqlite, react-native, page-refresh

In my home screen I have buttons that lead to different screens where a test is given.  When a user completes a test, the score is inserted into SQLite db file.  When user clicks on "Home" to go back to home screen, I want to display the new score in the results section.  Something like this:

Home Screen (App.js):

```
import Test1 from './Tests/Test1";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component { 
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          test1Score: 0,
      }

      //Retrieve last test score from SQLite table
      //setState for test1Score
      getTestScoreFromSQLiteDBAndSetState();
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <Button onPress={this.gotoTest1()} />
         <Text>Last test result: {this.state.test1Score}</Text>
   )}
}
```

Test1.js:

```
onTestComlete() {
   //insert the test score to the SQLite table
   insertTestScoreToSQLiteDB();
}

<Button onPress={navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')} title='Home' />
```

This is the basic setup, I'm not going to post the full codes as it gets too messy.

Right now I am able to insert the score to the db table.  Problem is in the HomeScreen, the getTestScoreFromSQLiteDBAndSetState part only execute when the first time the app is loaded.  So if I complete Test1, then press "Home" to navigate to HomeScreen, the score does not refresh.

Is there any technique in React Native to accomplish this?

---

EDIT:
For those who runs into similar issue, here's what I did based on the #2 solution of the accepted answer:

HomeScreen:

```
navigateToTest1 = () => {
   this.props.navigation.navigate('test1', {
       updateResult: this.updateTest1Results.bind(this)
   });
}

updateTest1Results = () => {
    //codes to retrieve result and setState goes here
}
```

Test1.js:

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
params.updateResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats happening is when you go back `react-navigation` doesn't load your screen again just show what was there before for better performance. You have a lot of possibilities some of them would look like this:

**1-**
Instead of using `navigation.navigate()` use `navigation.push()` that will create a new screen so it's going to update whatever there is to update.
**2-** you can call a function on `test1.js` from `homeScreen` before you navigate, just pass a function from `homescreen` to `test` as a param or as a prop (i don't know how it's constructed). On that function just have what you want to update, so the call to the sqlite table and the `setState`

**3-** use `react-navigation` events.

```
<NavigationEvents
  onWillFocus={payload => console.log('will focus',payload)}
  onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus',payload)}
  onWillBlur={payload => console.log('will blur',payload)}
  onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur',payload)}
/>
```

for more information about `react-navigation` events see [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html)
for more information about `navigation.push()` see [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#push)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I tried the second approach by writing a test function to simply setState to a test value in the HomeScreen, then pass the function as param to test1 and it worked.

Comment: I am still testing with this approach, but I would like to ask one more question regarding this approach.  Can I pass the function in the param to more than one screen?

Comment: Thanks, I tested by passing it through 3 screens, and it still works!